# Is it possible to store String array & int array to an array of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

'''

```
String array[] = new String[]{"ash","String","Ukara"};
int [] ar = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
Object i[][] = {array,ar};
```

'''
On adding int array to array of array showing this error as --> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to Object[]

Comment: You'll have to use `Integer [] ar = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4};`, but please consider using a custom class with named fields rather than pushing everything into a heterogeneous array.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `Object[][]` with `Object[]` and `Integer[]` as follows:

```
        Object[] arr1 = new Object[3];
        Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[3];
        Object[][] arr3 = {arr1, arr2};
```

Alternatively, other approaches such as a `HashMap<String, Integer>` or a new class might work better for your use case.

You could create a new class such as the following:

```
public class SomeClass {
   private String var1;
   private int var2;
}
```

Then create an array of this type:

```
SomeClass[] array = new SomeClass[3];
```